# How do I stop title-escape-sequences from clobbering my GNU screen titles?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I don't have control over the shell prompt or preexec, and I want to keep the titles I assign to screens.  Can I get screen to ignore title-escape-sequences?

Comment: You can set `TERMCAP` for screen, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Termcap

Comment: What is your terminal emulator? Can you reproduce the results when you use another emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a terminal whose description "looks" like `xterm`, `screen` assumes it does everything like `xterm`.  For whatever reason, it equates xterm-titles and xterm-mouse features:

- in [`termcap.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/termcap.c#n177), it checks if either the `TERM` environment variable contains the string "xterm" or "rxvt" — or it checks if there is a key definition for `kM` with the xterm-style `\033[M` string.
- if that check fails, (follow the `D_CXT` symbol in [`ansi.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/ansi.c#n1277) and [`display.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/display.c#n2140)), `screen` suppresses the escape sequences for the mouse and for the title.

So you can do it, but probably not as you want: you could set `TERM` to `vt100` (and `screen` wouldn't know about the mouse — or the title strings).

If you are really ambitious, you could modify `screen`, to make the two features separately configurable.

Comment: That sounds totally plausible, but I'm not seeing an actual answer?  Is the implication that I lie about my terminal or maybe patch screen?

Comment: What about modifying screen's termcap?  Is there a way to erase or override the specific capability or whatever the title function is called?

Comment: No - the **title** feature is not part of the termcap.  (By the way, it's more likely than not actually terminfo underneath).

Comment: I see.  What about a widely-available terminal specification that isn't \*xterm\*|\*rxvt\*, but has color?  I think I may just be asking too much.  At this point I'm considering changing the remote COMMAND_PROMPT despite it coming from ephemeral VMs and needing to do it frequently and for shared accounts, or using the 'linux' TERM, or ... giving up, I guess.

Comment: The `linux` entry also defines the mouse-prefix, so that would cause `screen` to assume it supports title-strings.